# Не работает OnCollisionEnter/OnTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создал пустой проект. Добавил куб и кинул на него RigidBody и Box Collider. Добавил второй куб, и накинул на него Box Collider.
Сделал скрипт и повесил его на первый куб (Пробывал и на второй):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter()
    {
        print("hit");
    }
}
```

Я уже перепробовал различные варианты (Также вешал RigidBody и Box Collider на всё что можно)
Я так же пробовал использовать OnTriggerEnter включив (и даже выключив) is Trigger но это тоже не работает.

Может кто скинуть простейший пример с этими функциями (Сцену)? В интернете не нашёл.

Comment: "Не работает OnCollisionEnter/OnTriggerEnter" - а ошибку в консоль не пишет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да. Ошибки не какой нет. Мне бы просто демо-сцену, где два кубика и скрипт. Я переписывая всё из ютуба - так и не смог сделать. Может быть баги нового обновления, просто в LTS работало раньше а я обновился на последнею версию...

Comment: ты используешь не тот метод. тебе нужно использовать сигнатуру `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274786/191482  - попробуйте ответ из этого вопроса

Comment: @Methorn, не обязательно, он должен работать и так. Но все равно - даже так он не работает.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Причины бездействия функций OnCollisionEnter/OnTriggerEnter/OnCollisionStay/OnTriggerStay](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-oncollisionenter-ontriggerenter-oncollisionstay-ontr)

Comment: @userpy нет, не должен, движок воспринимает только сигнатуру `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker а как же "The Collision class contains information about contact points, impact velocity etc. If you don't use collisionInfo in the function, leave out the collisionInfo parameter as this avoids unneccessary calculations" ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский впервые слышу, интересно, тогда да, мой поинт неправильный, спасибо.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker ну вот в доках посмотрел там есть) https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html  и другие тоже..  на сколько это давно в Юнити не могу сказать. с 5.3 точно  https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html  так что старо))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я уже, на форумах говорят, что раньше это "вроде бы" никак не влияло на производительность, сейчас, возможно, пофиксили. Что ж, буду знать :)

Comment: @aepot, мне он не помог.

Comment: @userpy в таком случае обновите вопрос, и расшифруйте с подробностями, что значит "не помог".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у коллайдеров Ваших объектов стоит флажок "Is Trigger", то нужно использовать "void OnTriggerEnter(Trigger trigger_name){}", если у коллайдеров нет флажка "Is Trigger", то нужно использовать "void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision_name){}".
Ещё не забудьте, что у ОБОИХ (у ДВУХ) этих объектов, если я не ошибаюсь, должен быть компонент "RigidBody".