# Функции событий столкновений: OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionEnter2D, OnCollisionStay, OnTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-faq

Этот пост содержит в себе ответы на такие частые вопросы, как:

- Для чего предназначены и как работают функции: OnCollisionEnter, OnTriggerEnter, OnCollisionEnter2D, OnTriggerStay, OnCollisionExit и подобные;
- Как их правильно вызывать / почему они не срабатывают;
- Что они принимают и возвращают;
- Почему функции OnCollision**Stay**/OnTrigger**Stay**/... перестают работать спустя несколько кадров, если изначально работали, а объект даже не двигался.

**ВАЖНО:** здесь также описано, что такое триггер, что он делает и чем отличается от обычного коллайдера.

Comment: Теперь надо, чтобы старшины/корифеи дали ОфИцИаЛьНоЕ разрешение иметь возможность закрывать вопросы по этой теме как дубликаты) 

Comment: Это право вам дает StackOverflow :)

Comment: @aepot <strike>Уряяя!!!<\strike> Превысокомного благодарен! :)

Comment: Если ответ точный и правильный - то можно закрывать.

Comment: Развлекаемся на последок, принятие закона о просветительской деятельности на носу. 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Список функций:

В первую очередь перечислим все подобные функции. Всего их **12**:

| События | Collider | Trigger |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Enter | [OnCollisionEnter(Collision)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) | [OnTriggerEnter(Collider)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) |
| Stay | [OnCollisionStay(Collision)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html) | [OnTriggerStay(Collider)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html) |
| Exit | [OnCollisionExit(Collision)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionExit.html) | [OnTriggerExit(Collider)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html) |

Те же функции, но для 2D объектов:

| События | Collider | Trigger |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Enter | [OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) | [OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) |
| Stay | [OnCollisionStay2D(Collision)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionStay2D.html) | [OnTriggerStay2D(Collider)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerStay2D.html) |
| Exit | [OnCollisionExit2D(Collision)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionExit2D.html) | [OnTriggerExit2D(Collider)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerExit2D.html) |

`! Все ссылки рабочие и направляют на страницу своей функции`

---

### О функциях On*Collision*... и их 2D версиях

**Из документации:**

- OnCollision**Enter** вызывается, когда этот Collider<sup>1</sup>/Rigidbody начал соприкосновение с другим Rigidbody/Collider.
- OnCollision**Stay** вызывается один раз в кадр для каждого Collider/Rigidbody, который касается другого Rigidbody/Collider.
- OnCollision**Exit** вызывается, когда Collider/Rigidbody прекращает контакт с другим Rigidbody/Collider.

> *Все вышеперечисленные тезисы верны в том числе и для 2D версий функций.*

**Аргументы:**
Все они принимают в качестве первого и единственного аргумента — `Collision` (*не путать с **`Collider`***). Класс `Collision` содержит информацию о точках соприкосновения, скорости воздействия и т.д.

**Требования:**

- **Оба** объекта **должны** иметь на себе компонент [Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html).
- У **обоих** объектов в компоненте Collider должно быть **ОТКЛЮЧЕНО** свойство [`isTrigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html).
- Хотя бы **один** из двух объектов должен иметь компонент [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html).
- У объекта(-ов) с компонентом Rigidbody должно быть **ОТКЛЮЧЕНО** свойство [`isKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html).

**Важно:**

1. События столкновений **отправляются** даже на неактивные компоненты.
2. События столкновений **НЕ отправляются** на объекты с отключенным или временно неактивным компонентом Rigidbody.

---

### О функциях-триггерах On*Trigger*... и их 2D версиях

> англ. trigger [ˈtrɪgə] - спусковой крючок, пусковой сигнал, *триггер*
>
> Collider с свойством триггера не является телесным и ни с кем не сталкивается (физически), а используется как зона, которая способна реагировать на события входа/выхода/нахождения в ней чего-либо и запуска неких сценариев.
>
> Любой объект будет проходить *сквозь* триггер, не оказывая физического воздействия.

**Из документации:**

- OnTrigger**Enter** вызывается, когда Collider other входит в триггер.
- OnTrigger**Stay** вызывается *практически*<sup>2</sup> каждый кадр для каждого Collider other, которые соприкасаются с триггером.
- OnTrigger**Exit** вызывается, когда Collider other перестает соприкасаться с триггером.

> *Все вышеперечисленные тезисы верны в том числе и для 2D версий функций.*

**Аргумент:**
Все они принимают в качестве первого и единственного *аргумента* — `Collider` (*не путать с **`Collision`***), то есть ссылку на компонент объекта, с которым произошло триггерное столкновение.

**Требования:**

- **Оба** объекта **должны** иметь на себе компонент [Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html).
- **РОВНО один** объект (**НЕ** два) должен быть помечен как триггер (то есть свойство [isTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html) должно быть равно true) в компоненте Collider.
- Хотя бы **один** из двух объектов должен иметь компонент [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html).

**Важно:**

1. Функции-триггеры вызываются в FixedUpdate **после** непосредственного входа в триггер/выхода из триггера и т.д., поэтому объекты, участвующие в столкновении, в момент вызова функции-триггера могут уже находиться не той позиции, где были в момент столкновения.
2. Функции-триггеры не являются непосредственной частью столкновений, а лишь функцией MonoBehaviour'a.
3. Функция OnTriggerStay зависит от физического таймера, поэтому нет необходимости вызывать ее каждый кадр — она может вызываться **НЕ** в каждом кадре.

---

**Помните также о том,** что если вы не используете аргументы, указываемые в функциях (Collision other, Collider collider...), вам следует их опустить: в таком случае ненужные расчеты не будут производиться. Например:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter () // Не нужен Collision collision — не пишем
{
...
}
```

---

### О переводе в "спящее" состояние

Многие могли сталкиваться с такой ситуацией: на объекте висит Collider, Rigidbody, всё настроено как надо, на объект повешен скрипт с функцией OnCollisionStay, OnTriggerStay или их 2D версиями. Однако при нахождении объекта в коллайдере, эти функции вдруг перестают работать! А если в них поместить `Debug.Log` для дебага, оказывается, что спустя несколько десятков кадров, объект просто **перестает** выполнять свою функцию, выводы в консоль прекращаются, и объект, который даже не двигался, будто *засыпает*! Почему такое происходит?

Дело в том, что Rigidbody действительно может **засыпать**!

Когда Rigidbody двигается медленнее определенной скорости, считается, что он остановился. После этого объект будет переведен в "спящий" режим. Это сделано для оптимизации: ресурсы процессора не будут расходоваться на обновление Rigidbody, пока он не "проснется" (т.е. снова придет в движение)

В некоторых случаях (например, когда передвижение физического объекта производится через т.н. "[телепортацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/936027)"), объект может не проснуться, хотя должен. В таком случае его можно принудительно разбудить функцией [WakeUp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.WakeUp.html).

Источник: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html

---

---

---

Сноски: 
<sup>1</sup> Здесь и далее под компонентом `Collider` понимается **любой** тип коллайдера, **любой** его наследник. То есть вы *можете* использовать [BoxCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider.html), [SphereCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SphereCollider.html), [CapsuleCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CapsuleCollider.html), любые 2D коллайдеры: [BoxCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html), [CircleCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CircleCollider2D.html) — или любой другой коллайдер, соответствующий вашим нуждам.

<sup>2</sup> `OnTriggerStay` вызывается *практически* каждый кадр, потому что она зависит от физического таймера, и нет необходимости вызывать ее каждый кадр.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123456/discussion-on-answer-by------oncollisione).