# Как проверить столкновение 2х объектов извне (они уничтожаются при столкновении)

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть пули и противники, при столкновении они уничтожаются и музыка не воспроизводится(т.к. объекты удаляются), я решил все сделать извне, кинуть код на пустой объект, обратиться ко всем колайдерам и проверять их на столкновение через IsTouching. Но ничего не происходит при попадании. Помогите, пожалуйста)

```
  public class DamageToTheEnemy : MonoBehaviour
  {
      GameObject[] enemy;
      GameObject[] bullet;
      [SerializeField] private AudioSource DamageEnemy;
      private void FixedUpdate()
      {
          enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy");
          bullet = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("bullet");
          Collider2D enemyColl;
          Collider2D bulletColl;  
          foreach (GameObject item in enemy)
          {
              enemyColl = item.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
              foreach (GameObject item2 in bullet)
              {
                  bulletColl = item2.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
                  if (enemyColl.IsTouching(bulletColl))
                  {
                      Debug.Log("Popal");
                      DamageEnemy.Play();
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: "FindGameObjects" два раза, да еще и каждый FixedUpdate!? Настоятельно не рекомендую практиковать подобное.

Comment: `я решил все сделать извне` - плохо решили. Не для того в unity [компонентно-ориентированное программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), чтобы вешать скрипты одних объектов на другие.

Comment: Вам нужно сделать отдельный скрипт для пули, которая при столкновении с игроком будет что-то делать. Или для игрока, который при столкновении с пулей тоже будем что-то делать. Столкновения можно реализовать либо через OnCollisionEnter либо OnCollisionEnter2D для – логично – 2D. Подробнее [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions) (самореклама:)

Comment: Не думаю, что при смерти врага он просто исчезает. Вы спавните объекты с какими-нибудь  эффектами, партикалс. Вот неужели так сложно точно так-же заспавнить объект с звуком?

Comment: Спасибо, ребят, я понял свою ошибку, попробую через эффекты сделать, гайд на ют нашел)