# Добрый вечер. Подскажите пожалуйста источники где можно прочитать про тригеры

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема: нужен тригер который будет считывать объекты проходящие через него. Пример: утка летит по прямой если она пролетит через тригер, тогда -1 хп игрока. если не пролетит значит все нормально.
( делаю игру охота на уток)
Если не сложно вообще книгу где описывается юнити и C# подробно.

я не сильно понимаю в программировании, но хочу разобраться.
спасибо.

Comment: Когда говорят про игру с охотой на уток, [я представляю это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trwva.jpg). И не понимаю, где там игрок с триггером. Быть может, вы про [коллайдеры](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для 2D

1. Кидаешь на GameObject, который будет триггером Box Collider 2D и выставляешь галочку у него Is Trigger.
2. Добавляешь скрипт с методом:

   private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision)
   {
   Debug.Log("Damage -1");
   }
3. У уток добавляешь компонент Rigidbody 2D и Box Collider 2D.
   Rigidbody 2D можно добавить не уткам а объекту с триггером.