# Как сделать так, чтобы проверка на коллизии осуществлялась каждый кадр? C#,Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Примерный код метода коллизий, который я использую сейчас:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.name.Equals == "Object")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1274787/373567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем проверка каждый кадр? Это же трудозатрано.

Если уж используте триггер, тогда может подойти **[OnTriggerStay2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html)**