# Как проверить касания объекта до пола unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Объект (персонаж) может делать прыжки в воздухе при нажатии пробела, а мне надо чтобы он мог это делать *только* находясь на земле. Мне нужна помощь.
Там, где нужно сделать эту проверку я пометил восклицательными знаками.

```
     void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (strafeLeft)
        {
            rb.AddForce(-strafeSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (strafeRight)
        {
            rb.AddForce(strafeSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (doJump)
        {
            if () // !!!!!
            {
                doJump = false; //Не делать прыжок
            } else
            {
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse); //Если персонаж касается пола, сделать прыжок

                doJump = false;
            }
       
        }

        if (rb.velocity.magnitude > runSpeed)   //Если скорость объекта превышает максимальную скорость
        {
            rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalized * runSpeed;  //Задать скорость на уровне максимальной
        }
    }
```

Comment: [
Вот решение вашей проблемы](https://answers.unity.com/questions/862880/disable-jumping-more-than-once.html)
Я считаю, это должно помочь вам

Comment: Мне не помогло:(

Comment: Вы можете устанавливать isGrounded=true при касании земли и  isGrounded=false, когда касания земли заканчивается. (OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionExit)

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос и даже больше находится здесь: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)

Comment: а еще бессмысленно использовать Time.deltaTime в фиксед апдейт, учитывая что там нужно использовать фикседДельтаТайм. Хотя здесь вообще лажа на лаже, ибо и то и другое не нужно использовать в случае движений на основе физики. И это при беглом взгляде на код....  Вобщем, все фигня, читай статью и переписывай с нуля.

Comment: @МаксимФисман как раз проблема в том, что я не знаю как это можно реализовать.

Comment: @МаксимФисман и еще, извини пожалуйста, но ты когда изменил мой вопрос, ты превратил его в "Объект (персонаж) может делать прыжки в воздухе при НАЖАТИИ ПРОБЕЛА ТОЛЬКО НАХОДЯСЬ НА ЗЕМЛЕ", а мне черт возьми надо было все наооборот

Comment: Прощу прощения. Я хотел написать `Мне НУЖНО, чтобы игрок мог прыгать только находясь на земле`, но я забыл исправить `может` на `нужно`. Еще раз извините:)

Comment: @МаксимФисман все бывает) так вы сможете помочь мне с кодом, пожалуйста?

Comment: Я напишу ответ, с объяснениями, хотя вам было бы полезно действительно почитать по ссылке данной Andrew, там очень много про перемещение.

Comment: @МаксимФисман спасибо большое. Просто я невероятный нуб в unity, и пока только развиваюсь)

Comment: На будущее: когда вы пишите вопрос: **НЕ** важно сколько вы программируете (нуб или нет), **НЕ** нужно писать `проверка через If`, так как If это и есть проверка и т.п., **НЕ** нужно строить длинные предложения, нужна краткость и четкость, **НЕ** нужно экспессировать `НУЖНА ПОМОЩЬ ТУТ`. Предпочитайте точки запятым. Легче читать несколько предложений, чем пытаться понять смысл и интонацию длинного предложения с большим кол-вом запятых.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сразу дам две ссылки:

- Полное описание того, как правильно реализовывать физическое и нефизическое движение объектов: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)
- Описание работы и применения функций OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionExit и так далее: [Функции событий столкновений: OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionEnter2D, OnCollisionStay, OnTriggerEnter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions)

---

Вам нужно реализовать простейшую систему:

1. Земля имеет коллайдер и тег "Ground"
2. Игрок имеет коллайдер
3. Скрипт игрока имеет переменную isGrounded
4. При начале коллизии с землей игрок становиться "приземленным": isGrounded=true
5. При окончании коллизии с землей игрок становиться "летающим": isGrounded=false
6. Игрок может прыгать, только если isGrounded==true

В класс игрока стоит добавить:

```
private bool isGrounded;

private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision) {
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
isGrounded = true;
}

private void OnCollisionExit (Collision collision) {
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
isGrounded = false;
}
}
```

На том месте, где у вас восклицательные знаки:

```
...
if (isGrounded) {
...
```

---

Однако, как уже сказал Andrew в комментариях у вас очень много ошибок. Например, вы реализовываете движение в FixedUpdate (подразумевая, что оно физическое), но при этом используете Time.deltaTime, хотя есть Time.fixedDeltaTime специально для FixedUpdate. Два условия (strafeRight), (strafeLeft) тоже выглядят как-то странно, к тому же у них в теле находится вызов одной и той же функции, только с противоположными параметрами `strafeSpeed` и `-strafeSpeed`. Да и вообще Time.deltaTime в AddForce выглядит странно (и еще странней, когда все это в FixedUpdate). В общем, читайте ссылочку, особенно первую.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое ❤

Comment: Даная реализация имеет проблемы с вертикальным взлетом в том случае если подойти к горе(вертикальному или почти вертикальному склону) и нажать кнопку прыжка. А так же не дает возможности прыжка по предметам вроде коробок. Вобщем, так себе совет. Там по ссылке с правильной реализацией передвижения персонажа есть вариант по-лучше. А этот вариант советую не использовать.