# OnTriggerStay2D не всегда работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как говорит сама Unity:

> OnTriggerStay2D вызывается каждый кадр для всех Collider2D.

Я столкнулся с проблемой, что когда я стою в этой области, у меня начинает срабатывать Debug.Log 53 раза и останавливается, если я сдвинусь(но всё же буду стоять в области), он снова заработает и отключиться, не могу понять в чем проблема?

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Stay");
}
```

[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8yuLvdnELI)

Comment: Важная вещь! Пожалуй, добавлю ее к своему [вопрос-ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions) по функциям столкновений

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дам свой ответ, так как считаю, ответ автора вопроса не соответствует рекомендациям о том, [как написать хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

---

Если [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) двигается медленнее определенной скорости, считается, что он остановился. После этого он будет переведен в "спящий режим" и будет оставаться таковым, пока к объекту не будет приложена [сила](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) или не произойдет [столкновения](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html). Это сделано для оптимизации: чтобы не тратить ресурсы на работу с неподвижным, "спящим" объектом.

В некоторых случаях, когда объект **с** Collider'ом, но **без** Rigidbody был передвинут через изменение Transform'а (т.н. *телепортация*), объект может не "проснуться" сам. Для его принудительного "разбуждения" существует функция [Rigidbody.WakeUp()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.WakeUp.html)

---

Информация является переводом страницы [официальной документации](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html)

Comment: Не совсем ясен смысл вопроса и ответа, это, по сути, копипаста документации ([и у нее уже есть перевод на русский](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html)).

Comment: Неплохой ответ, согласен с тем что ссылка может перестать работать.

Comment: Вопрос плохой, потому что он - частное от общего. Через поиск никто не найдет его с проблемой "у меня не работает OnTriggerStay" или с любым другим колбеком, кроме `OnTriggerStay2D`. Копипаста документации плохо работает здесь, потому последний абзац там написан изначально не особо точно. Передвижение статичного коллайдера - это нефизическое взаимодействие, очевидно, что оно не может повлиять на физическое состояние другого объекта в системе. И объект не "может", он **совершенно точно** не проснется от таких телодвижений статиков.

Comment: И уж если быть очень педантичным, не "скорость", а "кинетическая энергия". Вопросы про физику для меня - святое, потому что каких-то пару (?) лет назад на русском стэке думали, что `Translate` - это физическое движение именно из-за таких вот неточностей в ответах.

Answer (score 0):

Всё из-за того что Unity [оптимизирует](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html), и бросает Rigidbody2D в sleeping mode.

Comment: Давать ответы на собственный вопрос не запрещается, однако даже такие ответы должны соответствовать правилам того, [как дать хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Если кратко: ваш ответ не должен быть ответом-ссылкой. Ответ должен продолжать нести смысл, даже если ссылка перестанет работать.

Comment: Как дать хороший ответ - всего лишь справка, не правило.

Comment: Ну... с одной стороны "whatever terminology you like", но с другой большинство ответов, не соответствующих этой, как вы говорите, справке, минусуют или закрывают. Оно вам надо? Вот вопрос ваш хороший - у него +3, а на ответе +1-1=0

Comment: Хаха, кстати, это на русский перевели как "справка", а по-английски было (я так понимаю)  `help`. Так что это скорее "На помосчь!!!" :)))