# unity2d триггер не срабатывает

Tags: unity3d

Не понимаю почему не срабатывает триггер. Скрипт лежит на гг.

Объект

[image: Объект]

"главный герой"

[image: "главный герой"]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Функции событий столкновений: OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionEnter2D, OnCollisionStay, OnTriggerEnter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions)

Comment: Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема в OnTriggerEnter2d, должно быть [OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html). Используйте подсказки в коде которые дает Visual Studio.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У вас неправильное написание последняя d должна быть большой. Так же не стоит писать `collision.gameObject.tag`, ведь из Collider2D можно получить его без gameObject `collision.tag`