# Скрипт в Юнити не работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я написал скрипт чтобы когда игрок касался коллайдер монеток, монетки исчезали[image: сам скрипт]

Но он не работает!
Я назвал монетки Coins1
Дал им тег coins1, но ничего не работает, поставил Is Trigger на коллайдере и Is Kinematic в ригидбади, но, нифига(
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Функции событий столкновений: OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionEnter2D, OnCollisionStay, OnTriggerEnter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions)

Comment: код лучше вставлять текстом, а не картинкой, а тем более фотография

Comment: у вас лишняя точка с запятой в коде

Comment: Выделить текст кода - вставить в пост, фотку удалить.

Comment: `Но он не работает!` - надо всегда рассказывать, как именно вы поняли, что он не работает.

Comment: Вам помог мой ответ?

Comment: Минус вопросу за код, приложенный картинкой.

Answer (score 2):

У вас странный код, но главная ошибка в точке c запятой после ifа.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "coins1")
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }

}
```

Также условия работы OnTriggerEnter:

```
Оба объекта должны иметь на себе компонент Collider.

РОВНО один объект (НЕ два) должен быть помечен как триггер (то есть свойство isTrigger должно быть равно true) в компоненте Collider.

Хотя бы один из двух объектов должен иметь компонент Rigidbody.
```

Comment: У меня в скрипте почемуто coins1 красного цвета

Comment: @Chuvaaaaak Это подсветка твоей IDE. Потому что это строка и Visual Studio так настроена. Кстати вы внесли правки в свой вопрос. Пребывали ли вы скопировать и вставить мой код?

Comment: Отличные 2 опечатки в комментарии, еще одну и будет норм.

Answer (score 0):

У вас всех странный код. Ужаснее не придумаешь. Забудьте тэги. Это подход максимально не опытного программиста. Пишите так:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.TryGetComponent(typeof(Coin), out Coin coin))
        Destroy(coin);
}
```

Comment: У меня там почти все красным подчеркнуто

Comment: @Chuvaaaaak это даже не лечение по фотографии, с которого вы начали, а вообще по комментарию. Код ваш надо телепатически угадать? Вы C# синтаксис учили, отличаете методы, аргументы, классы, поля, свойства? Можете более конкретно выразить свои мысли, или же вам это не очень надо?

Comment: У него нет класса Coin наверное.