# Как реализовать следующую механику?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть игра, в которой есть 2 стенки, монетка и игрок. Игрок будет всегда двигаться в сторону монеты, но если нажать на экран то движение поменяется на обратное.  Как реализовать такую механику что если игрок касается монетки то она исчезает и спавнится в другом рандомном месте, при этом если игрок ее коснулся то она исчезает, и при этом на сцене была бы только одна монета?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject goal1; 
    public GameObject goal2; 

    bool check = false;
  

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (check) transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, goal1.transform.position, 3f * Time.deltaTime);
        if (!check) transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, goal2.transform.position, 3f * Time.deltaTime);

        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 1f);
    }

    public void change()
    {
        check = !check;
    }

}
```

вот начальный код

Comment: ну если одна, то при касании ее можно просто телепортировать в другое место

Comment: ну это понятно но как это сделать? у меня был метод
   
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (tag == "goal")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            score++;
        }
    }
но ничего не происходило, и я его удалил

Comment: если check сработал, то вставить ему обратно false и телепортнуть монетку, при этом движение продолжать в любом случае. Только рекомендуется логику игры с движениями обрабатывать не в Update, а в FixedUpdate, чтобы скорость игры не зависела от FPS.

Comment: По поводу триггеров почитайте это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274786/373567

Answer (score 0):

А что конкретно не получается реализовать?
Для начала нужно в движке сделать префаб монеты, повесить на него элемент Collider2D с галочкой IsTrigger (игра 2д я так понял), потом повесить какой-нибудь такой скрипт

```
using UnityEngine;    
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
    {
        void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.tag == "PLayer")
            {
                //Добавить очки

                //Убрать монету
                //Destroy(this)

                //Создать следующую монету
                //Instantiate(coin, рандомные координаты между двумя стенами)
            }
        }
    }
```