# Не работает OnTriggerEnter в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я только начинаю изучать unity и решил создать проект по видео из ютуба. Я всё делаю как на видео НО когда мой куб заходит в треггер ничего не происходит. RedCube это игрок, который входит в тригер (на нём есть Rigidbody). Cube(5) это тригер. Кнопки перехода работают как надо, а тригер нет. Я пробовал добавить Rigidbody и для тригера - не помогло, кликал на is Kinematic тоже без резултата. Ниже все картинки и код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] KeyCode keyOne;
[SerializeField] KeyCode keyTwo;
[SerializeField] Vector3 moveDirection;

private void FixedUpdate() { 
if (Input.GetKey(keyOne))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += moveDirection;
    }
if (Input.GetKey(keyTwo))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity -= moveDirection;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}

private void onTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (this.CompareTag("Player") && other.CompareTag("Finish"))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по идее должно работать при одновременном выполнении следующих условий:
1) на предполагаемом тригере коллайдер имеет флаг IsTrigger = true
2) на обоих взаимодействующих объектах есть Rigidbody

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274786/373567

Comment: onTriggerEnter с большой буквы нужно. OnTriggerEnter.