# OnTriggerEnter Работает всегда

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня есть несколько скриптов, использующих функцию private void OnTriggerEnter (заметьте - private)
Вот их список:
ScoreManager

```
private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col)
{ 
    if(col.tag == "radiy");
    { 
        score++;
        scoreDisplay.Text = score.ToString();
    }
}
```

он висит непосредственно на игроке и по идее, должен срабатывать, когда игрок сталкивается с объектом с тегом radiy

Collect

```
private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col)
{ 
   if(col.tag == "Player");
   { 
      Destroy(gameObject);
   }
}
```

Он висит на собираемом объекте и по идее, должен срабатывать, когда объект сталкивается с игроком с ясно каким тэгом

и последний: Enemy

```
private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider myCol)
{
   if(myCol.tag == "Player");
   {
       SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
   }
}
```

Этот скрипт висит на враге и когда игрок сталкивается с игроком, по идее его должно перебросить в главное меню

Но по итогу, когда игрок сталкивается с врагом, до перемещения в меню, видно, как к score прибавляется 1, как при собирании предмета
И так постоянно, при столкновении со всеми объектами, на которых висит скрипт с OnTriggerEnter и с коллайдером-триггером, происходит прибавление
Как сделать так, чтобы все скрипты действовали отдельно, вроде онтриггер private, но действует ВЕЗДЕ

Помогите пожалуйста(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274786/373567

Answer (score 1):

`private`, `public` откуда вы это взяли? Разницы нет, юнити вызывает свои функции через рефлексию и ей пофиг какие у них методы доступа.
Касаемо вашей проблемы, вы просто где-то накосячили.

Добавьте в `OnTriggerEnter` монеты банальный дебаг, чтобы понять, кто с кем на самом деле сталкивается: `Debug.Log(gameObject.name+" OnTriggerEnter "+myCol.gameObject.name);`

А вообще ваш код хлипкий во всех отношениях.

- tag это строковый литерал, что небезопасно из-за ошибок или опечаток, поэтому сравнивают по наличию компонента.
- сплошные триггеры. И монета триггер, и персонаж триггер, и наверняка еще и не триггер, и одно и то же событие обрабатывается сразу с двух сторон... нафига? Почему нет какой-нибудь сущности типа `GameScore`, ссылку на которую имеет каждая монетка и говорит ей при событии "начисли `x` очков" и имеет ссылку `UI`, который подписан на событие изменения, а персонаж об этом знать не знает, потому что это не его зона ответственности.
- враги отвечают за менеджмент сцен? Ты у каждого врага проставляешь одну и ту же цифру `sceneIndex`? Не его зона ответственности, он должен только фиксировать событие.