# Как сделать плавный подъём объекта при поподании в его коллайдер

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

подскажите, как сделать плавный подъём всех объектов, которые попали в колайдер другого объекта (OnTriggerEnter).

Comment: Попробуйте более подробно расписать вопрос. Добавить немного кода

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274786/373567

Comment: @aepot думаю в даном случае можно и как дубликат позначить

Comment: @Andrew готово.