# Если ставлю в бокс коллайдере тригер, обЪект просто проваливается

Tags: unity3d

Я в юнити не так долго и похоже пропустил что маленькое, но очень важное. Скажем есть платформа, на ней бокс колайдер 2д и риджитбоди 2д(кинематика). Есть персонаж, на нём так же бокс коллайдер и риджитбоди (динамический). Вот я настроил управление вроде ходит прыгает, всё хорошо. Но если я ставлю в бокс колайдере что это тригер, он просто проваливается через платформу. Я уже думал что может что-то со скриптом не так, но нет создал просто пустые обьекты с такими настройками, но без каких либо скриптов, результат тот же. Что я упустил?

Comment: Ну все правильно. Ты когда в играх входишь в какой-то триггер, ты упираешься в него или проходишь насквозь? Здесь так же. При столкновении коллайдера с коллайдером, они друг друга отталкивают от себя. При столкновении коллайдера с триггером, коллайдер спокойно проходит сквозь этот триггер.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Функции событий столкновений: OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionEnter2D, OnCollisionStay, OnTriggerEnter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions)

Comment: Спасибо, кажись понял

Answer (score 0):

Так если поставить триггер, то конечно он будет проваливаться, если хочешь чтобы он стоял, то не ставь галочку в триггере.