# OverlapBox не реагирует на другие коллайдеры

Tags: c#, unity3d, mono

Данный код нужен для включения физики у блока здания, если рядом нет других блоков.
Слой установлен Default, тег BuildingElement у блока присутствует.

При запуске этого скрипта, коллизия обнаруживается только с землёй (Plane), и то на расстоянии Y < 1.8

```
// isKinematic = true
void FixedUpdate()
{               
        uint connectedColliders = 0;
        if (!alreadyDisconnected && transform.localScale.x > 0.99f)
        {
            Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapBox(transform.localPosition, transform.localScale * 0.75f, transform.localRotation, _mask);
            foreach (Collider hitCollider in hitColliders)
            {
                // Отладчик ничего не выводит
                Debug.Log(name + ": checking connection to " + hitCollider.name);
                if (hitCollider.CompareTag("BuildingElement")) // || hitCollider.CompareTag("Ground")
                {
                    Debug.Log(name + " can connect to " + hitCollider.name);
                    connectedColliders++;
                }
            }
            if (connectedColliders > 0)
            {
                // Для отладки
                Debug.Log("Connected" + name);
            }
            else
            {
                alreadyDisconnected = true;
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
            }
            //Debug.Log("Connected colliders for " + transform.name + " is " + connectedColliders);
        }
 
}
```

Пример из документации работает аналогичным образом.

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274786/373567), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/936027/373567)

Comment: @aepot
[Ссылка на документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html)

Твои ссылки не связаны с вопросом. Вся физика у меня и так обрабатывается в FixedUpdate, а Physics.OverlapBox может вызываться вне методов, связанных с коллизией.

Comment: Вторая ссылка, самый конец. Вы же не читали, так? И уже говорите, что я не прав.

Comment: Это я уже применил, и это **никак** не относится к проблеме. Плюсом кинематический Rigidbody не поддерживает Continious collision detection.

Comment: Ок, я не шарю, извините что вмешался.