# Не обновляется переменная в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Trigger_Destroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int score=0;
    
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject attached = gameObject;
        _tag = gameObject.tag;
    }
        
    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        score +=1;
        Debug.Log(score);
    }  
}
```

Когда персонаж входит в триггер, значение счета не обновляется. Сколько бы раз я не собирал триггер, в консоли счет всегда равен единице.

Как мне сделать чтобы счет обновлялся, когда я беру триггер?

Comment: Обработка тригера на персонаже должна быть, а не на том, что вы уничтожаете, и очки там же.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274786/373567

Comment: aepot, действительно.  Перенес очки на игрока и все стало работать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Моя ошибка была в том, что приложенный скрипт, который считал очки, висел на объектах, которые создавались в начале игры, а потом, когда я их собирал, они удалялись.Очки, которые я пытался считать, удалялись вместе с объектами, из-за чего в консоли всегда была единица.

Создал на своем игроке новую переменную "score" и добавляю значения к ней и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри вот это https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9XcnmPZjB8&t=5s, там все подробно рассказано. Скорее всего ты выставил не те настройки в Триггере.
В методе start(),зачем создаешь экземпляр своего gameObject если ты можешь напрямую к нему обращаться, _tag не объявлен нигде.
И сделай проверку в OnTriggerEnter какой объект входит в колизию, иначе любой объект который попадет в колизию будет увеличивать твой счетчик.

Comment: У него все ок с тригером, он срабатывает. Вы невнимательно прочитали вопрос.