# Не удаляется объект Destroy Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bottle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Model;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    void OnTriggerStay (Collider other) {
        if (other.tag=="Player" & Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)) {
            Destroy (Model);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот возможные решения:

1. Убедиться что Model это объект на сцене (Hierarchy) а не с директории (Project).

> `Destroy()` - уничтожает объект со сцены, а не префабы

2. Убедиться что Bottle обрабатывает триггеры (имеет коллайдер), провести отладку (можно установить к примеру `Debug.Log("bottle triggered on Player")`).

> [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/Функции-событий-столкновений-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions) - ссылка на помощь с обработкой столкновений

3. Убедиться что у объекта столкновения есть тег `Player` и он написан без ошибок и точно также как и при данной проверке.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Удалил объект из префабов и все заработало.