# Не обрабатывает событие функции OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь обработать событие с помощью OnTriggerEnter, суть события заключается в том что когда объект 1 уровня пересекает collider другого объекта 1 уровня - оба объекта удаляются и заместо первого объекта спавнится объект уровня 2.

Пробовал через дебаг на наличие откликов, итог: Не отображается что объект вообще пересекает collider другого объекта.

```
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if ( other.gameObject.name == "Item 1(Clone)")
    {
        
        switch (PropSpawn.Api.cloneItems.Count)
        {
            case 0:
                Destroy(PropSpawn.Api.cloneItems[0]);
                newItem2 = Instantiate(PropSpawn.Api.Item2);
                cloneItems2.Add(newItem2.transform);
                cloneItems2[0].position = PropSpawn.Api.cloneItems[0].position;
                break;
        }
       

    }

}
```

}

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274786/373567

Comment: Читал, не помогло.

Comment: Может, всё таки не OnColliderEnter, а OnCollisionEnter?

Comment: @KOTlK ну он же читал....так что всё же Collider.....

Comment: Я пробовал Collision и Trigger.

Comment: Надо не пробовать, а читать документацию и писать правильно. Затем ставить точки останова и отлаживать код. А пока вопрос на закрытие как "вопрос-опечатка".

Comment: Так а в каком месте не правильно сделал

Comment: Сейчас я переписал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, когда создаешь функцию OnTriggerEnter(){} в сценарии. На объекте должен висеть Rigidbody

Answer (score 0):

Возможно ты неправильно указал имя тэга, либо у тебя в коллайдере на игровом объекте отсутствует галочка isTriggered. В конце концов ты можешь использовать onTriggeredEnter либо еще поэксперементировать с подобными функциями. Кстати мне кажется лучше оператор switch поменять на if, в данном случае код будет смотреться лучше.

Comment: Галочка есть, switch нужен чтобы с каждой точкой спавна работать.

Comment: Имя тега правильное.

Comment: if и switch практически одно и тоже, с каждой точкой спавна можно работать и через if, тут непринципиально.  Кстати в коллайдере объекта установлена галочка isTriggered?

Comment: Да, галочка установлена.

Comment: дебаг ты куда записывал, до оператора if или внутри его?

Comment: Внутри его записывал.

Comment: запиши до if, если сообщение в консоль выведется, то проблема будет в условии оператора if

Comment: @Alle  какой доистореческий способ узнать заходит ли в if ))  Может всё же посоветовать debugger с точками останова?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Как это сделать ? Я Jun разработчик.