# С# Unity. Как исправить подергивание персонажа в 2D игре

Tags: c#, unity3d

хочу задать вопрос знатокам.
Написал скрипт бесконечного движения персонажа вперед (2D Раннер на очки).
Казалось ничего сложного(куча видео и статей в интернете), но после билда появился баг - во время игры при любых обстоятельствах игра рандомно поддергивается, как будто перемотка видео на секунду-две дальше. проседания фпс не замечал, эксперементировал с физикой и переписывал способ задания скорости объекту, ничего не помогает. на телефоне часто проявляется с разной переодичностью(тел далеко не древний, многое тянет) на пк очень редко и при всем этом около 400-500 фпс в мониторинге

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float MoveSpeed = 5;
    [SerializeField] private float JumpForce = 15;
    [SerializeField] private float JumpHorizontalSpeed = 1;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject JumpFX;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource _audio;
    [SerializeField] private GameData data;

    private Rigidbody2D RigBody;
    private Collider2D PlayerCollider;
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField]private GameTimerUI gameTimer;

    private bool OnGround;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask Ground;

    void Start()
    {
        RigBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        PlayerCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        OnGround = Physics2D.IsTouchingLayers(PlayerCollider, Ground);
        if (RigBody.velocity.x < MoveSpeed)
        {
            RigBody.velocity = new Vector2(MoveSpeed, RigBody.velocity.y);
        }

        if (OnGround)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Jump", false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("Jump", true);
        }
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (OnGround)
        {
            _audio.PlayOneShot(data.jumpSound);
            Instantiate(JumpFX, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            RigBody.velocity = new Vector2(RigBody.velocity.x, JumpForce);
            RigBody.AddForce(new Vector3(JumpHorizontalSpeed, 0, 0),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        else
        {
            RigBody.velocity = new Vector2(MoveSpeed, RigBody.velocity.y);
        }
    }
    public void StartGaming()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
        gameTimer.StartGameTime();
    }
}


//camera

    'void Start()
    {
        LastPos = MainPlayer.transform.position;
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        DistToMove = MainPlayer.transform.position.x - LastPos.x;

        MainCamera.transform.position = new Vector3(MainCamera.transform.position.x + DistToMove , MainCamera.transform.position.y, MainCamera.transform.position.z);

        LastPos = MainPlayer.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Знаю Unity на уровне чайника, но хорошо знаю шарп. Здесь особо оптимизировать страшного нечего, но можно отполировать, например [вход и выход из коллайдера с землей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274786/373567), пусть Unity проверяет коллизии, а не FixedUpdate. Ну и управление анимацией как раз в коллизию бы и унес. Если не читали про движение персонажа, почитайте [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567).

Comment: Спасибо) вчера перепробовал эти варианты и правильные и не правильные :D

Comment: Думал может-быть стоит на коллайдерах сделать проверку нахождения на земле(так для игры самой приятнее будет в плане механики), но кажется с данной проблемой не должно быть связано т.к. к горизонтальному перемещению это не имеет отношения(кроме физического столкновения тел, не отраженных в коде)опять-же комбинации физических настроек пробовал менять толку ноль(

Comment: Ну, взрослые дядки профилируют код, смотрят где какие его учатки жрут ресурсы. Где-то может мусор скапливаться, при чистке которого как раз могут возникать рандомные тормоза. То есть вы `Instantiate` делаете если очень часто и много, а Unity за вами потом убирается, когда скрипты отомрут. Следите за ресурсами.

Comment: Не подскажете где информацию доступную взять по методам и как это происходит?)

Comment: Не подскажу, не знаю как это в Unity делается. CPU/Memory Profiling, Object Pooling - куда-то туда копать.

Comment: нашел profiler встроенный, местами просадки до 15фпс..... пока сделал ограничение кадров в скрипте на телефоне зрению незаметны лаги особо....буду копать дальше

Comment: Чтобы красиво было, 60 ФПС должно тянуть

Comment: Возможно проблема в камере. Камера перемещается (следует за персонажем)? Если да, то отвечающий за это скрипт совершает передвижение в Update()? Если и это так, то измените не LateUpdate().

Comment: да, но я проверял через профайлер и там ничего страшного. Правда через FixedUpdate реализованно, но на мониторинге как-будто на рендер изображения все указывает все просадки на гпу идут

Comment: я в коде внизу добавил фрагмент отвечающий за камеру

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в моей ситуации помог переход на альфа версию Unity 2023.1.0a6.754 и установка Application.targetFrameRate = 150 (не 60, т.к. на целевом устройстве матрица на 144гц) Результат не идеальный, но достаточно плавное движение получилось.

Обновление положения камеры оставил LateUpdate.

Странно но на любой актуальной LTS версии Unity лично мне больше ничего не помогло, в коде катастрофичного ничего не нашлось.