# Не сразу нажимается клавиша E в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Написал скрипт, в котором при нажатии клавиши E через `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)` происходят некоторые действия, но чтобы все сработало на E нужно нажать 3-5 раз, хотя если поставить вместо клавиши E какую-либо другую, то все будет с 1 раза. В других играх (не моих), да и в принципе клавиша E нормально работает. Что делать?

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject use;
[SerializeField] private AudioClip[] useAudioClips;
[SerializeField] private AudioSource audioSource;
[SerializeField] private GameObject panel;
[SerializeField] private GameObject flashlight;
private GameObject collisionDoor;
[SerializeField] private GameObject player;

private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Door"))
    {
        use.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(useAudioClips[0]);
            panel.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("ToBlackPanel");
            flashlight.SetActive(false);
            if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Forest") StartCoroutine(ToHouse());
            if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "House") 
            {
                collisionDoor = collision.gameObject;
                StartCoroutine(Transition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код скрипта, отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)` [нужно вызывать](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) в методе `Update` а не в `OnTriggerStay`.

> Call this function from the `Update` function, since the state gets reset each frame. It will not return true until the user has released the key and pressed it again.

```
private bool isDoor;
private SpriteRenderer renderer;
private Animator panelAnimator;

private void Start()
{
    renderer = use.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    panelAnimator = panel.GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (isDoor && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(useAudioClips[0]);
        panelAnimator.Play("ToBlackPanel");
        flashlight.SetActive(false);
        switch (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name)
        {
            case "Forest":
                StartCoroutine(ToHouse());
                break;
            case "House":
                StartCoroutine(Transition());
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Door"))
    {
        collisionDoor = collision.gameObject;
        renderer.color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
        isDoor = true;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Door"))
    {
        isDoor = false;
    }
}
```

[Функции событий столкновений: OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionEnter2D, OnCollisionStay, OnTriggerEnter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274786/373567)