# collision между обьектами и клонами в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я написал программу, где при клике пуля(клон, созданный через `instatiate`) создается и через секунду исчезает. Но как можно сделать так, чтобы при попадания к какому-то обьекту, пуля исчезнет?

Я пробовал использовать `OnCollisionEnter2D()`, но это не помогло(в коде видно), также я проверил [этот сайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions), но там не было ничего нужного.

Вот сам код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class firing : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 mousePos;
    private Camera mainCamera;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float force;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(){
        Destroy(gameObject, 0.1f);
    }
    void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        mousePos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 direction = mousePos - transform.position;
        Vector3 rotation = transform.position - mousePos;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x, direction.y).normalized * force;
        float rot = Mathf.Atan2(rotation.y, rotation.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rot + 90);
        Destroy(gameObject, 1.0f);

        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Похоже, что нужно удалить "Destroy(gameObject, 1.0f);" в конце метода Start.

Comment: Не помогло @rotabor