# не работает функция OnTriggerEnter2D в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я новичок в Unity и C#. У меня возникла проблема с OnTriggerEnter2D, когда я подхожу к квадрату на котором весит скрипт и circle collider 2D с галочкой "isTrigger", то не чего не происходит. Вот мой срипт:

```
public class StartGolovolomka : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;


    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Trigger", true);
        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {


        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Trigger", false);
        }


    }
}
```

Помогите Пожалуйста.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274786/373567