# Не правильно работает OnCollisionEnter2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть объекты, у которых должно увеличиваться число при соприкосновении с таким же объектом, но даже без соприкосновения число увеличивается, но при этом при этом на элементе между ними число не увеличивается, не понимаю почему так происходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "bubble" && collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite == this.GetComponent<Image>().sprite)
    {
        collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Bobble>().count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1274787/373567 почитайте, вдруг там что-то полезное есть. Пробовали отлаживать, чтобы понять, для каких именно столкновений срабатывает коллизия? Нужная коллизия есть или же только ненужная возникает? Сравнивать спрайты тоде так себе идея. Я бы тип объекта в публичном поле хранил и его сравнивал, а не спрайты.